# iOS Safari ignores overflow hidden code in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I think this is where problem is

```
  document.getElementsByClassName("content-area").style.postion = "relative";
  document.getElementsByClassName("content-area").style.overflow-y = "hidden";
```

Comment: `overflow-x:hidden;` try that

Answer (score 1):

You cant use style.overflow-y .. below code will work. [More info](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_overflowy.asp)

```
document.getElementsByClassName("content-area").style.overflowY = "hidden";
```

Comment: sorry I made mistake in writing the code in question. but overflowY and even plain overflow="hidden" doesn't work.